# How to do user input in Jenkisfile to carry on with terraform apply?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, terraform, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I'm running a Jenkins pipeline job using `Jenkinsfile`. The primary purpose is to run  **`terraform <plan|apply>`**, based on the *choice parameter* to select either `plan` or `apply`, like this:

```
stages {
  stage('tf_run') {
    steps { 
      sh '''#!/usr/bin/env bash
        terragrunt ${Action} --terragrunt-source "/var/temp/tf_modules//${tfm}"
      '''
    }
  }
}
```

Where `Action` is the choice-parameter variable, it's all good for the ***plan*** but failing for ***apply*** as it asks for the confirmation whether to proceed or not, and the job is falling instantly. What can I do here so that users get to type `yes`/`no` (or select from the list), which then can be passed on to the `terraform apply`?

I got stuck in the middle, and I'd appreciate it if anyone could put me in the right direction. I appreciate any help you can provide.

-S

Comment: The problem here is that the Jenkins Pipeline input step would precede the shell script method for executing the Terraform CLI (which is end-to-end). Consequently, you would be approving a `terraform apply` prior to ever viewing the plan, which is not what you want. This pipeline could be refactored to fit normal Terraform deployment pipelines where the plan is generated, approved, and then passed to the apply if approved. If that is ok, then I can write the answer for you.

Comment: Also alternatively if this were to fit conventional Terraform git workflows, then you could generate the plan on PR and apply on merge, which would also work for you if the interface were moved to your SCM server and interfaced to your Jenkins Pipeline.

Comment: thanks @MattSchuchard for the offer.  That was exactly my issue with `input` step. I'm open to other options, as long as I'm not blindly running the `-auto-approve`. I'd really appreciate if you could write the answer, the way you mentioned.

Comment: Added an answer. There are honestly a bunch of different blueprints for this kind of pipeline, so there are many opportunities for customization and expansion beyond the functional answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fit the use case, the Jenkins Pipeline will have three steps:

- Generate the plan file
- Query user input for plan approval
- Apply the plan file if approved

Assumption: you claim the pipeline is successful for `plan`, which implies to me that `Action` and `tfm` are environment variables (i.e. `env.Action`), because otherwise the String argument to the `sh` step method is invalid. Given that assumption:

(answer now modified upon request to demonstrate `tfm` as a pipeline parameter and no longer is in the `env` object)

```
parameters {
  string(name: 'tfm', description: 'Terraform module to act upon.')
}

stages {
  stage('TF Plan') {
    steps {
      // execute plan and capture plan output 
      sh(
         label:  'Terraform Plan',
         script: "terragrunt plan -out=plan.tfplan -no-color --terragrunt-source '/var/temp/tf_modules//${params.tfm}'"
      )
    }
  }
  stage('TF Apply') {
    // only execute stage if apply is desired
    when { expression { return env.Action == 'apply' } }
    steps {
      // query for user approval of plan
      input(message: 'Click "proceed" to approve the above Terraform Plan')
      // apply the plan if approved
      sh(
         label:  'Terraform Apply',
         script: 'terraform apply -auto-approve -input=false -no-color plan.tfplan'
      )
    }
  }
}
```

You may also want to add the equivalent of `env.TF_IN_AUTOMATION = true` to the `environment` directive. This can be helpful when executing Terraform in a pipeline.

If you also modify the pipeline `agent` to be e.g. the Terraform CLI image running as a container, then the plan output file will also need to be preserved between stages.

Comment: thanks @Matt Schuchard! The bash script that I'm using is a little more complicated than that and `${Action}` is the parameter (so cane be used anywhere) but `${tfm}`  is a bash variable. Any idea how can I assign that to a groovy variable, so that can be used in the later _stage{}_?

Comment: @MacUsers Yes I can also answer that quick question, but I am not sure how it relates.

Comment: as I mentioned before, The actual bash script that I got to run has a bit more than those few simple lines and there few common variables, generated in/by bash, including `${tfm}` that I need to use in both stages (Plan and apply). What I'm planning is to introduce another stage, before _plan_ and _apply_ to generate all those required variables and then use 'em in two latter stages. Hence, asked the additional question. True, it's not directly related. But appreciate if you can show me.

Comment: @MacUsers Ok I updated the answer based on your previous comment, but based on your new comment you would need to do a significant update to the question to provide information about that use case and your example code. You should ask a new question with that information.

Comment: Thanks @Matt Schuchard! I already tried `parameters { ... }` block but wouldn't work for me as those variables are rather dynamically formed than statically typed. Instead I did that in a `script { ...}` with multi-line `sh( ... )` - not the best, I assume but worked for me.

Comment: The issue is though: the job is stuck at `Proceed or Abort` step - it's not moving forward clicking either. Any idea if I'm missing something here?

Comment: 1. You should mention that in the next question, as that seems like unexpected behavior. That should work for you either way, so that would be interesting to take a deeper look at. 2. That sounds weird and counter to documentation. Does the log show the next step executes, or does it pause at the `input` step method indefinitely?

Comment: It doesn't look like going anywhere at all; just waiting at the input step indefinitely. No log entry after *Proceed or Abort* at all.

Comment: Thanks @Matt Schuchard for the code sample. I had to change it a bit to fit in my scenario but pretty much what you did. It still not fully working tough, as mentioned before,  getting stuck at the `input(...)` step but that seems to be a different issue. Posted a separate  question for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `terraform apply -auto-approve` within your Jenkins Job.

[See Docs](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/apply)

Tip: You can add condition in Jenkins stage() when a user choose parameter plan than there will be no -auto-approve option added automatically, else the command will append -auto-approve option.

```
stage(plan&apply){
  if ${USER_INPUT} == "plan"{
    terraform plan
  }
  else{
   terraform apply -auto-approve
  }
}
```

Note: Above Jenkins code might not match to proper Ans but can be taken as example.

Comment: Here is the problem: I don't want to use the `-auto-approve`, which is a risky business. For an `apply`, I like to replicate the same behavior, on the GUI, as using CLI.